# How to make the plugin YouCompleteMe show libraries an import has?

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me

My vim is nearly an ide, just have one thing missing. Is it possible to have this plugin show the modules of imported libs?

Trying to get this feature that other ides have. Like how that small dropdown screen comes up showing the modules, allowing you autocomplete when selecting when you do for example: `lib.` and the modules/methods are shown.

I like vim too much, I could use sublime with vim maps but it's not the same, other ides like visual studio are hugely cumbersome and just unnecessary imo, my vim ide is much better, I'm just missing this one feature

Comment: For which language are you searching thus feature? Python, Javascript, Typescript, ...?

Comment: oops sorry, I really thought I wrote python, I've got the jedi python plugin as well

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt got any ideas?

Comment: if you know how to go to methods in other files that woukd be cool too. I've tried to read the docs so I can use these features, I'm either getting it wrong something might be wrong with my machine

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. Do you want to see the possible method of a package? Do you want to see the possible package?  Both should be part of the Python language server YouCompleteMe is using (pyright). Maybe could you give us an example of code and the completion you would like to get. It will precise the quesrion and help us in the answer.

Comment: I have tested using YouCompleteMe and both package completion and function/method are working fine with Python. I would need more details about your need to reproduce your problem and propose you a solution :-)